# Directors directing compatible movies

Tags: knowledge, visual, movies

- *Each director in the image directed a movie which is compatible with an association, a gemstone, an organ and a tool.*
- *All those movies complete something.*

---

[image]

---

***WHICH ARE THOSE MOVIES AND WHAT DO THEY COMPLETE?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, note that the first line, referencing "an association, a gemstone, an organ and a tool", refers to:

> **card suits**: club (an association), diamond (a gemstone), heart (an organ), spade (a tool).

It is then possible for us to find one film for each pictured director such that when put together...

> ...their titles contain the **names of all of the cards in a suit**: Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King.

This is a very tricky task, as many of these directors have directed *a lot* of movies, several of which contain valid answers for this puzzle. However, the only way I have found which completes the set is as follows:

> *Top row:*
>  Jack Conway – A Tale of **Two** Cities
>  Billy Wilder – **Ace** in the Hole
>  John Huston – The African **Queen**
>  Akira Kurasawa – **Seven** Samurai
>  Cecil B. DeMille – The **Ten** Commandments
>
>  *Middle row:*
>  Bob Rafelson – **Five** Easy Pieces
>  Dario Argento – The Cat o’ **Nine** Tails
>  Leonard Nimoy – **Three** Men and a Baby
>  Fred Schepisi – **Six** Degrees of Separation
>  Mike Newell – **Four** Weddings and a Funeral
>
>  *Bottom row:*
>  Peter Jackson – Lord of the Rings: The Return of the **King**
>  Christopher McQuarrie – **Jack** Reacher
>  Quentin Tarantino – The Hateful **Eight**

Comment: Great work! I'd have chosen another of Peter's movies as the more obvious candidate, but your choice works too.

Comment: @Jaap Indeed, multiple options there! I went for the one that won more Oscars :)

Comment: @Stiv Outstanding!